# Django: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'dict'

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am in my views.py and want to perform a mathamatical calculation for my accounting project...

So I have done something like this:

```
@login_required
def ledger1_detail_view(request,pk2, pk3):
    ledger1_details = get_object_or_404(ledger1, pk=pk2)
    selectdatefield_details = get_object_or_404(selectdatefield, pk=pk3)

    qs  = journal.objects.filter(User=request.user, Company=company_details.pk, By=ledger1_details.pk, Date__gte=selectdatefield_details.Start_Date, Date__lte=selectdatefield_details.End_Date)

    qs2 = journal.objects.filter(User=request.user, Company=company_details.pk, To=ledger1_details.pk, Date__gte=selectdatefield_details.Start_Date, Date__lte=selectdatefield_details.End_Date)    

    total_debit  = qs.aggregate(Sum('Debit'))

    total_credit = qs2.aggregate(Sum('Credit'))

   closing_balance = ledger1_details.Opening_Balance + total_debit - total_credit

    context = {

    'ledger1_details' : ledger1_details,
    'selectdatefield_details' : selectdatefield_details,
    'total_debit'     : total_debit,
    'total_credit'    : total_credit,
    'journal_debit'   : qs,
    'journal_credit'  : qs2,
    'closing_balance' : closing_balance,        

}   

return render(request, 'accounting_double_entry/ledger1_details.html', context)
```

The problem is in this line of code:

```
  closing_balance = ledger1_details.Opening_Balance + total_debit - total_credit
```

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'decimal.Decimal' and 'dict'
```

This are my models:

```
class ledger1(models.Model):
    Creation_Date   = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    name            = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    group1_Name     = models.ForeignKey(group1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True,null=True)
    Opening_Balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=19,decimal_places=2,blank=True)

class journal(models.Model):
    Date       = models.DateField()
    By         = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Debitledgers')
    To         = models.ForeignKey(ledger1,on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='Creditledgers')
    Debit      = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)
    Credit     = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2)

class selectdatefield(models.Model):
    Start_Date = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
    End_Date   = models.DateField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Do anyone have any idea about how to do this type of mathematical calculation in django views???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your aggregates return `dict`ionaries, not values, so:

```
# incorrect way to work with aggregates
total_debit  = qs.aggregate(Sum('Debit'))
total_credit = qs2.aggregate(Sum('Credit'))

# ... later you use these values like ...
closing_balance = ledger1_details.Opening_Balance + total_debit - total_credit
```

this will return:

```
# result of the above method
total_debit == { 'Debit__sum': 123 }
total_credit == { 'Credit__sum': 456 }
```

and it makes no sense to add a number (`Decimal`) together with a dictionary.

You can fetch the *value* that corresponds with the dictionary, so we need to unwrap these. Furthermore it might be possible that there are no related `journal` objects, in which case the outcome will be `None`, not `0.0`, we can use the [**`Coalesce`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/database-functions/#coalesce) function for this:

```
# performing arithmetic with aggregates
from django.db.models import Value
from django.db.models.functions import Coalesce

total_debit = qs.aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Debit'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
total_credit = qs2.aggregate(the_sum=Coalesce(Sum('Credit'), Value(0)))['the_sum']
closing_balance = ledger1_details.Opening_Balance + total_debit - total_credit
```

You can also just fetch the `'sum__Debit'` and `'sum__Credit'` key, but personally I think named arguments are more "robust", since if you later change the aggregate, these will still work.

Comment: I think it will return "Debit__sum" instead of "sum__Debit"...anyways if I name the argument it is giving me this error now "AttributeError at 
'decimal.Decimal' object has no attribute 'the_sum'"

Comment: Did you make edits to the `closing_balance = ledger1_details.Opening_Balance + total_debit - total_credit` line?

Comment: Yes I have done this  " closing_balance = ledger1_details.Opening_Balance + total_debit.the_sum - total_credit.the_sum1 "...

Comment: @NiladryKar: you should **not** add any attribute calls! Where do you read that in this answer?

Comment: @NiladryKar: yes because here we *unpack* the dictionary in the `.aggregate(..)` call...

Comment: The last line should be `closing_balance = ledger1_details.Opening_Balance + total_debit - total_credit`, and the previous two like in the *second* code sample. So you should replace the lines in the first code sample with the ones in the second code sample...

Comment: @NiladryKar: what error? You psted two different ones, please edit the question with the *full* traceback.

Comment: The same error which I have posted in my question is showing after I done the solution you provided...

Comment: @NiladryKar: hold on, the code fragment with `total_debit == ...`, is not part of the solution, it is used to demonstrate why the code will never work. You should thus use the *last* code fragment.

Comment: I have done this " total_debit = qs.aggregate(the_sum=Sum('Debit'))['the_sum']
total_credit = qs2.aggregate(the_sum=Sum('Credit'))['the_sum']
closing_balance = ledger1_details.Opening_Balance + total_debit - total_credit"        ...But getting the same error as I have posted in my question

Comment: @NiladryKar: are you sure it is not `None`? Is it possible that there are no `Journal` objects for a given `ledger1`?

Comment: @NiladryKar: in case a ledger has not per se any `journal`s, you should "shield" this case with a `Coalesce`.

Comment: How can I pass these in template???I mean the total_debit part previously I have don this "total_debit.Debit__sum" in my template

Comment: @NiladryKar: again, by simply using `{{ total_debit }}`, by using a dictionary, you all make it hopelessly more complex and "unstable", since now your template makes quite some assumptions about your view, and assumptions are typically not a very good idea.